# VBA Visio select objects by color

Tags: vba, visio, shapesheet

I would like to select the objects by the color.

So far I did something like this:

```
 If Vshp.CellsU("FillForegnd").FormulaU = "RGB(128,128,128)" Then
 sel.Select Vshp, visSelect
 End If
```

But I see no reaction at all.

[image]

I picked it from here:

[Visio change color of all child elements using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413207/visio-change-color-of-all-child-elements-using-vba)

and here:

[VBA Change the Color of a Rounded Rectangle in Visio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405404/vba-change-the-color-of-a-rounded-rectangle-in-visio)

Is there any way of how I could pick up the shapes by their exact RGB colour?

UPDATE:

With the following approach:

```
 If Vshp.Shapes(4).CellsU("FillForegnd").FormulaU = "RGB(128,128,128)" 
 Then
 sel.Select Vshp, visSelect
 End If
```

I receive the following error:

**Invalid Sheet identifier**

Pointing out the line:
If Vshp.Shapes(4).CellsU("FillForegnd").FormulaU = "RGB(128,128,128)"

The following threads:
["Shape.ConnectedShapes method (Visio)" example from Microsoft site give "Invalid Sheet Identifier" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67267370/shape-connectedshapes-method-visio-example-from-microsoft-site-give-invalid)
http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=9713.0
Weren't helpful for me

**UPDATE II:**

I realized, that the subshape cannot be  `.Shape(4)`, because it's the text.
I just need to know how to read the [Drawing explorer window](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/hardware-and-creative/9781849680141/2/ch02lvl1sec05/the-drawing-explorer-window), because I see multiple of the same shapes in my layer and I have no clue which one should correspond to the `Cabinet(Fibre Schematic).2125`, or alternatively could I pick them up by name?.

[image]

**UPDATE III**

After searching the solution I found a nice hint here:

http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=7577.0

but unfortunately it doesn't work with the manner I would like to apply:

The current code:

```
 For Each subshp In vShp.Shapes
 If subshp.CellsU("FillForeground").FormulaU = "RGB(128,128,128)" Then
   ActiveWindow.Select subshp, visSubSelect
   End If
 Next subshp
```

Throws the error:

**Unexpected end of file**

At the line:

```
   If subshp.CellsU("FillForeground").FormulaU = "RGB(128,128,128)" Then
```

Comment: In your case you must check sub-shapes color! You really need select few sub-shapes wih line `sel.Select Vshp, visSelect`?

Comment: I need to select a few whole shapes (including sub-shapes) in one line, but I guess, selection all sub-shapes by their colour can be good.

Comment: At your picture with **Drawing Explorer Window** you have a sort by layer view in the diagram. there is another shape view, where you can see the shape and its children

Comment: The only thing I can see it's right-click and layer properties. I cannot sort the layer by its objects therefore I am not aware of other shapes than the text (.Shapes(4)).

Answer (score 1):

> I need to select a few whole shapes (including sub-shapes) in one line, but I guess, selection all sub-shapes by their colour can be good

**IMHO** selection of sub-shapes in not good idea!
Hope these gif-animations can explain difference.

1. Align selected shapes
   [image: Align selected shapes]
2. Align selected sub-shapes
   [image: Align selected sub-shapes]

---

Even in we select all shape with some color.
[image]
How we can align them **ALL**?

you can explore the contents of the group using the **Drawing Explorer window**
[image: Drawing Explorer window]

---

> `If subshp.CellsU("FillForeground").FormulaU = "RGB(128,128,128)" Then`

Por this purpose better use [ResultStr property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.cell.resultstr). With syntax like
`If subshp.CellsU("FillForeground").Resultstr(visNone) = "RGB(128,128,128)"`
This picture show difference of representation **Formulas** in ShapeSheet (FormulaU in VBA) and **Values** (ResultStr).
[image: Formulas vs Values]

**Themes** in MS Visio are most ugliest feature.
[image: Themes]
If you apply som Theme and Shapes changed their fill colors, but in ShapeSheet in this cell you can see constant in Values or Formulas representation!!!

Comment: Yes, but so far I just need some way of selecting them by color.

Comment: I don't think about aligning them, but move them to the top for example. If I could have them selected, I could think about another approach leading to sort the whole schematic shaps alphabetically by the text (Shapes(4)).

Comment: Updated my query, as I found a new hint.

Comment: I prefer [system Visio colors](https://forumimage.ru/uploads/20160221/145608220051857697.png) (color number in [range 0-23](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.visdefaultcolors)).  I dont like use RGB colors, because it have [delimetres problem for non-English languages](https://visio-getbb-ru.translate.goog/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=844&_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=ru&_x_tr_pto=wapp).

Comment: It doesn't matter which type of colors it could be, the problem is, that I can't select any object with the color.

Comment: I'm trying to test a shape's value of `shp.CellsU("LineColor").ResultStr(visNone) ` and I get the value "0", not something containing an RGB value.

Comment: What about `shp.CellsU("LineColor").Result(visNone)` output?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, unlike the previous answer, you would be able to select the whole shape by its sub-shape.

Basing on this thread:
http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=7577.0

We are able to select any subshape falling inside the shape, but also the shape by the subshape properties.

```
For Each vShp In VPage.Shapes
 For Each subShp In vShp.Shapes
  If subShp.CellsU("FillForegnd").FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(191,127,255))" Then
   ActiveWindow.Select vShp, visSubSelect
  End If
 Next subShp
Next vShp
```

It's important to pick up the color straight from the formula presented in the ShapeSheet design

[image]

Once used in he manner as above, we are able to select just the particular part of our drawing, which shapes include the subshapes with this colour.

[image]